std::chrono::time_point is slightly off
If I do the following:
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::duration::zero();
std::cout << time.count() << std::endl;
time += std::chrono::years(2024 - 1970);
std::cout << time.count() << std::endl;

It comes out to be Monday, January 1, 2024 2:16:48 AM, not 12 AM. I want to represent historic calendar dates. year_month_day and hh_mm_ss are available for use, but I enjoy having the ability of getting time_point::time_since_epoch(). I need this because it is a convenient way of storing date and time data in a database as a single int64. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?
As I see it my only options are to handle the timings myself and keep using std::chrono, but this defeats the purpose of using std::chrono, or to use chrono::year_month_day and chrono::hh_mm_ss and deal with the database in a different way.

"It comes out to be Monday, January 1, 2024 2:16:48 AM" - but time is a duration, and time.count() is an integral value. I don't see how your posted code can print such a date. Please post a [mre].

"years is equal to 365.2425 days (the average length of a Gregorian year)." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration. You can't use std::chrono::years for actual dates.

Do you want to shift the time by amount of seconds or amount of years? You are doing the former now because std::chrono::years does not count the true number of seconds between two January 1st dates, it only does 365*24*3600*n conversion. Doing the latter is not that trivial in epoch time.

@wohlstad I meant the integral value reported is the equivalent of 2:16:48 AM. That is the entire code. I copy pasted it from my main function.

@Quimby I wanted to shift by a number of years. I suppose I'll just use year_month_day if it is difficult to make this work in epoch time.

You are doing chronological computations.  You want calendrical computations.  See this answer for a description of each and how to do them.  The linked answer uses months as a motivating example but years works the same way.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

@Eshy: "I enjoy having the ability of getting time_point::time_since_epoch()." Stop enjoying that. Store the data in a database as text. If you need to work with dates, you need to work with dates, not "time since epochs". The whole point of chrono is that you shouldn't work with bare epoch counts. The more high-level information you store, the fewer "surprising" results like this you will encounter.

See this answer for a more in-depth description of chronological computations vs calendrical computations.
But in short, this:
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::duration::zero();
std::cout << time.count() << std::endl;
time += std::chrono::years(2024 - 1970);
std::cout << time.count() << std::endl;

is a chronological computation.  I characterize it as such because it adds a regular unit to a count of regular units.  A single std::chrono::years is nothing more than 31'556'952 seconds which is the precise length of the average year in the civil calendar (other calendars will have years of different average length).
And in truth, I would not even count the above code as necessarily well posed because it clearly intends that time be a point in time, and yet it is is declared as a duration.  A better way to perform this chronological computation would be:
Demo:
using namespace std::literals;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time{};  // zero-initialize
std::cout << time << '\n';   // 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
time += 2024y - 1970y;
std::cout << time << '\n';   // 2024-01-01 02:16:48.000000000

Now time is a time_point.  One can still get the internal count out of it if desired:
std::cout << time.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';

To perform a calendrical computation one must convert to a calendrical system (there are several), perform the computation in the calendrical system, and then (if desired) convert back to the chronological system.
For example:
Demo:
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time{};  // zero-initialize
std::cout << time << '\n';   // 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
std::chrono::year_month_day ymd = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(time);
time = std::chrono::sys_days{ymd + (2024y - 1970y)};
std::cout << time << '\n';   // 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000000

As a demonstration of using an alternative calendrical computation consider this:
std::chrono::year_month_weekday ymd = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(time);
time = std::chrono::sys_days{ymd + (2024y - 1970y)};
std::cout << time << '\n';   // 2024-01-04 00:00:00.000000000

Now instead of adding 54 years to Jan 1, 1970 one is adding 54 years to the first Thursday of Jan 1970 to get the first Thursday of Jan 2024.  Indeed year_month_weekday is truly a full demonstration of an alternate calendar.  User written calendars modeling the Julian, Chinese or Islamic calendars could also be used, and likely give different results as well.

I discourage falling back to the C timing API unless you need to do so to interface with legacy code.  C++20 and forward has a superset of the date/time functionality of the old C API.  It is also much safer and easier to use.
If you identify functionality in the C timing API that you aren't sure how to do in modern <chrono>, just ask here on stackoverflow and I'm sure someone will be glad to show you how to do it.

Your
time += std::chrono::years(2024 - 1970);

suggests that you want to work with "calendar times", not timestamps.
C++20 adds support for calendars and timezones (which are necessary -- as an example, on the day where daylight savings time changes, a day might have 23 or 25 hours, instead of the customary 24). I haven't used these yet, though.
Check out the overview of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono
However, "traditional" calendar-calls are often sufficient. As an example, if you have a std::chrono::system_clock::time_point, you can use std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t() to get a time_t for it. You can then use std::localtime to break that time_t down into your local second/minute/hour/day/month/year. There is also a std::mktime() doing the opposite, and std::chrono::system_block::from_time_t to get back to a time_point.
The interesting thing about std::mktime is that it allows "invalid" values as input, and "fixes" them. As an example, assume it's "Feb 28", and you want to get to the next day. You can just add 1 to the day, making it "Feb 29" -- if that particular year doesn't have a "Feb 29", it will just be treated like "Mar 1" instead.
Likewise, if you cross the daylight saving time switch, adding +1 to the day can give different results compared to adding +24 to the hour. So, forget about "a day has 24 hours" or "a year has 365 days", and do arithmetic with exactly the fields that you actually need.
Of course, "historic dates"... don't really work with any of this. Timezone databases have historic information, but that only goes back so far... and aside from time_t only being a 32-bit value on some systems, there's no real reason for the timezone database to have ancient information.
On the positive side, things like daylight savings time wasn't really a thing until recently, and calendars were pretty consistent over centuries. So, the general rules laid down for the Gregorian calendar can be used. Places did have their own local time until trains made long-distance travel feasible and every town having its own clock was causing issues, but most historic dates don't need that kind of accuracy anyway.
